# printing theano.tensor without having any idea about the shape and type of the tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, theano

I am debugging a code which I haven't written. I want to print out `state_below_` variable which is calculated as following:

```
state_below_ = tensor.dot(state_below*emb_dropout[1], tparams[pp(prefix, 'W')]) +\
        tparams[pp(prefix, 'b')]
```

When I use `state_below_.eval()`, I get

> MissingInputError: ("An input of the graph, used to compute
>   Reshape{1}(y_sampler, TensorConstant{(1,) of -1}), was not provided
>   and not given a value.Use the Theano flag
>   exception_verbosity='high',for more information on this error.",
>   y_sampler)

error. How can I print this damn "state_below_" value?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using purely symbolic variable, you have to compile a function with respective inputs and outputs. Then you have to make a call to your function with constant values for respective symbolic variables. 
Else, if you are using a shared variables, the way you have written will work. 
The documentation to [function](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/compile/function.html) , [shared variable](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#converting-from-python-objects)

Comment: can you give an example over my problem?

Comment: for instance, I have such a list: outs = [next_probs, next_sample, next_state]. When I say print outs, I get this output: [Softmax.0, argmax, Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0]. How can I print next_sample value?

Comment: What you have are symbolic variables. Did you try compiling the "function" ? 
Like, 
function = theano.function([List of Inpuy Variables], [outs])
out = function(values for input)

Comment: The "out" will have whatever your compiled function has returned. Else, if you don't want to use compiled function, you can use shared Variables. Refer to the documentation link in the answer.